# is there an efficient way to run multiple BFt-tests on multiple vectors?

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with a dozen columns,
and i want to run the function "ttestBF" on 5 of them.
each row is a subject.
and i want to compare inside each column between 2 conditions (male/female).
what i did looks like this:

```
 ttestBF(df$sheker[df$sex == "f"],
         df$sheker[df$sex == "m"])
```

five times for each column.
i have tried looking in the history of similar questions but they were quite different.
is there a way to do this more efficiently?